# React Native what does the bind null do in a structure like this: someFunction.bind(null, someHook)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, bind

`AScreen` shows `AComponent`, `component` has a button to increment an index from 0, when the index hits 5, `AComponent` will be replaced by `BComponent`. `BComponent` has a button that can bring back `AComponent` and re-set index to 0.

What does `backToACallBack.bind(null, useCurrentIndex)` do in the following codes? Why bind `null`?

```
export default function AScreen() : JSX.Element {
  const backToACallBack = (useCurrentIndex) => {
    const [, setCurrentIndex] = useCurrentIndex;
    setCurrentIndex(0);
  };

  return (
    <AComponent
      panel={( useCurrentIndex ) => (
        <BComponent onBackToACallBack={backToACallBack.bind(null, useCurrentIndex)} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

export interface AComponentProps {
  panel: (
    useCurrentIndex: [number, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>],
  ) => JSX.Element;
}

export default function AComponent({ panel }: AComponentProps): JSX.Element {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={ currentIndex >=5 ? { display:none } : { flex:1 } }>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)}>
          <Text>INCREMENT</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={ currentIndex >=5 ? { flex:1 } : { display:none } }>
        {panel([currentIndex, setCurrentIndex])}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export interface BComponentProps {
  onBackToACallBack: () => void;
}

export default function BComponent({ onBackToACallBack }: BComponentProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onBackToACallBack}>
      <Text>BACK TO A</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `.bind` is the `this` value to be used in the function `.bind` is being called on - but arrow functions always have lexical `this`, and the `backToACallBack` doesn't reference `this` anyway, so it doesn't matter what the first value passed to `.bind` is.

The second argument to `.bind` is the first argument that the function gets invoked with. Eg `function foo(a){ ... } const bound = foo.bind(null, 5);` results in, when `bound` is called, `foo` being invoked with an `a` parameter of `5`.

Similarly, here, `backToACallBack.bind(null, useCurrentIndex)` results in a function which, when called, calls `backToACallBack` with an argument of `useCurrentIndex`.

Another method of doing the same thing without `.bind` would be:

```
<BComponent onBackToACallBack={() => { backToACallBack(useCurrentIndex); }} />
```

If you use `.bind`, but the function being bound is an arrow function or doesn't reference `this`, the first argument can be *anything*, since it goes unused (but you need to pass a first argument so that you can then pass a second argument, the `useCurrentIndex`). Using an anonymous function like I did above instead of `.bind` might make the intent a bit clearer.

Comment: To fully replicate `.bind`,  `(...args) => backToACallBack(useCurrentIndex, ...args)` would pass on additional arguments such as Event objects.